# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS: DNS address could not be found DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE

Tags: networking, dns, vpn

so I am new to ubuntu and while trying to connect to any website or even do a simple search I get this error of DNS address could not be found DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE. I was using proton vpn before but after disconnecting the issue remained. Unfortunately I uninstalled proton vpn and now am stuck.

Comment: Contact Proton VPN and find out how to remove their product if you want it gone completely. It sounds like t was not fully removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the file `/etc/resolv.conf`.
I think it might still be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

It probably happened due to an update with Proton. I had the same problem. If you had Proton still available you would just go to the "split tunneling" section and hit the + sign next to your specific app and that will probably fix the problem.