# DNS address could not be found - DNS_Probe_Possible error

Tags: internet, dns

I'm new to Ubuntu (I have Mate 22.04) and I am not able to connect to the internet anymore ( with any browser), probably caused by Proton VPN uninstall. The error messages I receive are

> DNS address could not be found and DNS_Probe_Possible

My browsers can't connect. So I re-installed Proton, but it didn't solve the problem. I've succeeded to connect to the web by changing my name server address to 8.8.8.8 in the file: etc\resolv.conf - except that Ubuntu rewrote that modification, Now inside the etc/resolv.conf folder, I have a resolv.conf.d folder, and there is no nameserver address anymore, but 3 files named: Base, Head and Tail - no place to input nameserver 8.8.8.8  I can't either find a place to input that nameserver address in Ubuntu. The only browser that can connect is Thor (VPN). I'm on wired internet.

Does someone in Ubuntu community have a permanent solution for that annoying problem?

Comment: Did you reboot?  What does your `resolvectl status` output say for DNS servers when you're connected to a network (NOT VPN)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DNS not resolved on Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426658/dns-not-resolved-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop)

Comment: Also see [Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS: DNS address could not be found DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435003/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-dns-address-could-not-be-found-dns-probe-possible).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer. I followed one of your chat answer for a similar problem, made a few queries you suggested on my terminal and it showed that my DNS was 8.8.8.8 !!! So my problem is now resolved; I can browse with all my browsers without DNS Possible Probe showing up. Great! Though I still cannot see any nameserver address text inside the resolvconf folder (like before the DNS broke). Only the 3 files I mentioned here above).

The query for: resolvectl status gave this output:

Global
Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8

Link 2 (ens5)
Current Scopes: none
Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wls1)
Current Scopes: none
Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (ipv6leakintrf0)
Current Scopes: none
Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 5 (proton0)
Current Scopes: DNS
Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
DNS Servers: 10.22.0.1
DNS Domain: ~.

which I don't know what it means. Thanks again!